# How to input the output of one filtered query into another groupby query in SQL in Python (subquery)?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count, window-functions

Here is the full table: (code at end)

```py
query = """
SELECT * FROM businesses
"""
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
df
```

[image: businesses table]

I would like a single SQL query which finds the top 2 popular cities where owners have at least 2 shops. With expected output being London and Leicester:

[image: tables]

I currently know how to group by city to find top 2 cities:

```py
# Top 2 popular cities
query1 = """
SELECT city, COUNT(*) as frequency
FROM businesses
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 2
"""
df = pd.read_sql_query(query1, conn)
df
```

And how to filter to find owners who have at least 2 shops:

```py
# Owners who have at least 2 shops
query2 = """
SELECT owner, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM businesses
GROUP BY owner
HAVING count >= 2
ORDER BY count DESC
"""
df = pd.read_sql_query(query2, conn)
df
```

But I don't know how to combine query1 and query 2 into one query.

I would really appreciate any help with this, trying to self-learn SQL :)

Here is the code which creates the database if you'd like to follow along:

```py
# import libraries
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

# create database
conn = sqlite3.connect("my_db.db")

# create table
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS businesses;")
query = """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS businesses (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    city TEXT NOT NULL,
    owner TEXT NOT NULL
    )
"""
cur.execute(query)
conn.commit()

# add rows to table
query = """
INSERT INTO businesses
    (id, name, city, owner)
VALUES
    (1, "Shop A", "London", "Tom"),
    (2, "Shop B", "London", "Tom"),
    (3, "Shop C", "London", "Tom"),
    (4, "Shop D", "Luton", "Alice"),
    (5, "Shop E", "Leeds", "Jenny"),
    (6, "Shop F", "Leicester", "James"),
    (7, "Shop G", "Leicester", "James"),
    (8, "Shop H", "Leicester", "Emma"),
    (9, "Shop I", "Leicester", "Emma"),
    (10, "Shop J", "Liverpool", "James"),
    (11, "Shop K", "Liverpool", "James"),
    (12, "Shop L", "Liverpool", "George"),
    (13, "Shop M", "Shefield", "Mary"),
    (14, "Shop N", "Shefield", "Mary"),
    (15, "Shop O", "Cambridge", "Oliver"),
    (16, "Shop P", "Manchester", "Harry")
"""
cur.execute(query)
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should group by city and owner, filter the results in the `HAVING` clause and then use `SUM()` window function to get the count for each city:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city, 
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION By city) AS count
FROM businesses
GROUP BY city, owner
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 2;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=ce23e6e3adc4c0c8bf048d56af036afd).

Answer (score 1):

Using https://sqliteonline.com/ was able to get the result you wanted:

```
SELECT 
  city, 
  count(owner) 
FROM 
  businesses 
WHERE 
  owner in (
    SELECT 
      owner AS count 
    FROM 
      businesses 
    GROUP BY 
      owner 
    HAVING 
      count >= 2 
    ORDER BY 
      count DESC
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  city 
ORDER BY 
  count(owner) DESC 
LIMIT 
  2;
```

Result:
[image]

There is a good video about SQL subqueries which I recommend watching:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJIEIzF7tDw

Please let me know if it worked or if the python code might be needed as well.